# SSIS SharePoint List Source : how can we use variable in camlquery

Tags: sharepoint, ssis

In my SSIS solution I use the component SharePoint List Source, it works fine when the query in CamlQuery is fixed string, but it doesn't work i f i try to use vriable in my query.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.
Best regards
Bachir

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.
I set the custom properties of the SharePoint List source  by using Integration Services expressions.  I create the expressions on the containing Data Flow task.
Bachir